# How to make Drop Down Optional as it is coming mandatory after populating it with javascript api MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

For creating cascading drop down in MVC Code first approach following has been implemented and previously optional drop down is coming as mandatory when running the project.

1. I am using LINQ to populate View
2. Using API in Javascript for populating the 2nd Drop Down based on selection of 1st drop down

I also want to get the text of selected Id of 2nd drop down which is coming as null when i try using Hidden field for capturing it through javascript on('change', function ()

Rest all is standard following is the javascript in View:

```
        $('#firstddl').on('change', function () {
            console.log('firstddl changed!!');

            //Jquery ajax to school api with selected dropdown value
            var url = "/api/Project/secondddl/" + $(this).val();
            $.getJSON(url, function (data) {

                console.log(data);

                var items = ["<option>Select Drop down</option>"];
                $.each(data, function (key, val) {

                    items.push("<option value='" + val.id + "'>" + val.ddlName + "</option>");
                });
                $("#secondddl").empty("");
                $("#secondddl").append(items);
                $("#SelectedfirstddlText").val($("#firstddl option:selected").text());
                $("#selectedsecondddlText").val($("#secondddl option:selected").text());
            });
        ...
```

Please let me know how can avoid mandatory validation from second drop down list and save the selected value in db.

Comment: Is it model validation causing it ? Remove the `Required` attribute on the relevant property then.

Comment: There is not required validation in the model it automatically started coming when i implemented cascading using api in View(cshtml file). Should i remove @HTML helper?